# Drop down menu in ASP.net is not working(MVC)

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-10"
     @Html.LabelFor(expression: x => Model.MOCType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     @Html.DropDownListFor(expression: x => Model.MOCType, selectList: new SelectList("CPPSMOC", "SPRDMOC"), optionLabel: "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "text-danger" })

  </div>
 </div>
```

Drop down menu code is given above in MVC method of ASP.net but results are not as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a static list, try with below code.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.MOCType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })   
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.MOCType, new SelectList(
                                              new List<Object>{ 
                                                   new { value = 0 , text = "CPPSMOC"  },
                                                   new { value = 1 , text = "SPRDMOC" }
                                                },"value","text",2),
                                               new { @class = "text-danger" })

  </div>
 </div>
```

If you have dynamic list then try with below code.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.MOCType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })   
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MOCType, new SelectList(
              Model.DropdownSelectList, "id", "name", 1), new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the SelectList must be IEnumerable, Please pass the custom list (IEnumrable) to the SelectList.